# Has anyone deployed a succesful SSAS on docker?

Tags: ssas, docker

I'm trying to create a docker image that contains MS SQL server, analysis services, and restore a db (bak) and a cube (abf). The Sql server part is the easy stuff, and I imagine that the restore will be too quite simple... the unsuccessful part is the installation of SSAS.

I've already tried without success:

- Splitting images (1 for MSSQL and 1 for SSAS)
- installing from the inside of a container with SQL Server installed
- trying differents account (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE,BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS)

Any chance that anyone has done something similar or is "impossible" to achieve such a [working] image?

This is a clean sample of what I'm doing:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

ENV exe "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=840945"    
ENV box "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=840944"

ENV sa_password="_" \
    attach_dbs="[]" \
    ACCEPT_EULA="_" \
    sa_password_path="C:\ProgramData\Docker\secrets\sa-password" \
    appname="demo"
    
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

WORKDIR /

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:box -OutFile SQL.box ; \
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:exe -OutFile SQL.exe ; \
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\SQL.exe -ArgumentList /qs, /x:setup ; \
        .\setup\setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQL,AS,Tools /UPDATEENABLED=0 /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic  /SQLSVCACCOUNT='domain\user' /SQLSVCPASSWORD='somepassword' /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS='domain\user' /ASSVCACCOUNT='domain\user' /ASSVCPASSWORD='somepassword' /ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS='domain\user' ; \
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force SQL.exe, SQL.box, setup
```

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully built a SSAS image:

https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/windowscontainers/tree/master/sqlserver2022as

I decided to keep SSAS split from the MSSQL image to keep images as slim as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Windocks offers Windows SQL Server containes, and plans to release support for SSAS and SSIS early in 2020 (ie., Jan).

Comment: Do you have a source for this?